# Rename files matching pattern in a loop - Bash

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I have been trying to rename some specific files based on a table but with no success. It either renames all files or gives error.

The directory contains hundreds of files named with long barcodes and I want to rename only files containing the patter _1_.

Example

```
barcode_1_barcode_SL484171.fastq.gz   barcode_2_barcode_SL484171.fastq.gz   barcode_1_barcode_SL484370.fastq.gz   barcode_2_barcode_SL484370.fastq.gz
```

mytable.txt

| oldname | newname |
| --- | --- |
| barcode_1_barcode_SL484171 | Description1 |
| barcode_2_barcode_SL484171 | Description1 |
| barcode_1_barcode_SL484370 | Description2 |
| barcode_2_barcode_SL484370 | Description2 |

Desire output:

Description1.R1.fastq.gz     Description2.R1.fastq.gz

As you can see in the table there are two files per description but I only want to rename the ones with the _1_ pattern.

Code I have tried:

```
for i in *_1_*.fastq.gz; do read oldname newname; mv "$oldname" "$newname".R1.fastq.gz; done < mytable.txt

for i in $(grep '_1_' mytable.txt); do read -r oldname newname; mv ${oldname} ${newname}.R1.fastq.gz; done < mytable.txt

for i in $(grep '_1_' mytable.txt); do oldname=$(cut -f1 $i);newname=$(cut -f2 $i); ln -s ${oldname} ${newname}.R1.fastq.gz; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r oldname newname
do 
    if [[ $oldname =~ "_1_" ]]
    then 
        mv $oldname $newname
    fi
done < mytable.txt
```

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you explained your code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r files; do                 ##: loop through the output of `grep 'barcode_1_barcode.*' table.txt`
  while read -ru9 old_name prefix; do        ##: loop through the output of `find . -name 'barcode_1_barcode*.gz' | grep -f <(cut -d' ' -f1 table.txt`
    if [[ $files == *"$old_name"* ]]; then   ##: If the filename from the output of find matches the first field of table.txt (space delimite)
      old_filename="${files%.fastq.gz}"      ##: Extract the filename without the fast.gz extesntion
      extension="${files#"$old_filename"}"   ##: Extract the extention .fast.gz without the filename
      # mv -v "$files" "$prefix.R1${extension}"
      printf '%s %s %s ==> %s\n' mv -v "$files" "$prefix.R1${extension}"  ##: Rename the files to the desired output
    fi
  done 9< <(grep 'barcode_1_barcode.*' table.txt)
done < <(find . -name 'barcode_1_barcode*.gz' | grep -f <(cut -d' ' -f1 table.txt) ) ##: Remain the first column/field of table.txt
```

---

Output from the OP's sample data/files.

```
renamed './barcode_1_barcode_SL484370.fastq.gz' -> 'Description2.R1.fastq.gz'
renamed './barcode_1_barcode_SL484171.fastq.gz' -> 'Description1.R1.fastq.gz'
```

---

- If you're satisfied with the output either move the `#` from the front of `mv` to the

  front of `printf` or just delete the entire line with `printf` and remove the `#` from

  `mv` in order for `mv` to actually rename the files.